# How to add ssh public keys to server?

Tags: ssh

On all of my servers I added the below in `.ssh`

```
git_id_rsa  
git_id_rsa.pub
```

The public key was added to git hub.

When I do a `git clone` I get the below:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How do I add the keys I placed in ssh so the its aware that the public keys that are located on github are in ssh folder?

Comment: For those that decrement a post...my lord..,provide a reason. Tsk tsk tsk.

Comment: The down vote is because adding a public key to a chain is such a fundamental skill that is covered in millions of places across the web, you clearly have not done minimal effort to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host githubs.host.name 
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git_id_rsa
```

and replace `githubs.host.name` with the relevant host name you need to communicate with GitHub.